# Optimizing Postgres Count For Aggregated Select

Tags: postgresql, indexing, group-by, count, query-optimization

I have a query that is intended to retrieve the counts of each grouped product like so

```
SELECT
  product_name,
  product_color,
  (array_agg("product_distributor"))[1] AS "product_distributor",
  (array_agg("product_release"))[1] AS "product_release",
  COUNT(*) AS "count"
FROM
  product
WHERE
  product.id IN (
    SELECT
      id
    FROM
      product
    WHERE
      (product_name ilike "%red%"
       OR product_color ilike "%red%")
      AND product_type = 1)
GROUP BY
  product_name, product_color
LIMIT
  1000
OFFSET
  0
```

This query is run on the following table

```
       Column        |           Type           | Collation | Nullable | Default 
---------------------+--------------------------+-----------+----------+---------
 product_type        | integer                  |           | not null | 
 id                  | integer                  |           | not null | 
 product_name        | citext                   |           | not null | 
 product_color       | character varying(255)   |           |          |
 product_distributor | integer                  |           |          | 
 product_release     | timestamp with time zone |           |          | 
 created_at          | timestamp with time zone |           | not null | 
 updated_at          | timestamp with time zone |           | not null |
Indexes:
    "product_pkey" PRIMARY KEY, btree (id)
    "product_distributer_index" btree (product_distributor)
    "product_product_type_name_color" UNIQUE, btree (product_type, name, color)
    "product_product_type_index" btree (product_type)
    "product_name_color_index" btree (name, color)
Foreign-key constraints:
    "product_product_type_fkey" FOREIGN KEY (product_type) REFERENCES product_type(id) ON UPDATE CASCADE ON DELETE CASCADE
    "product_product_distributor_id" FOREIGN KEY (product_distributor) REFERENCES product_distributor(id)
```

How can I improve the performance of this query, specifically the COUNT(*) portion, which when removed improves the query but is requisite?

Comment: Could you please share the results from explain (analyze, verbose, buffers) for this statement? Otherwise nobody knows where most of the time is spent

Comment: What is the point of `WHERE pk in (select pk from same_table WHERE ...)`?  If you just move the WHERE conditions out of the subquery into the main WHERE, wouldn't the results be identical?

Comment: This is probably tangential to the question about improving performance, but what's up with `"product_product_type_name_color" UNIQUE, btree (product_type, name, color)`? Specifically the column names appear to be `product_name` and `product_color` rather than `name` and `color`.  Similar with the 5th index as well. Couldn't reproduce by doing things like renaming the columns. Can someone shed some light on this apparent discrepancy?

Answer (score 0):

You may try using an `INNER JOIN` in place of a `WHERE ... IN` clause.

```
WITH selected_products AS (
    SELECT id
    FROM product
    WHERE (product_name ilike "%red%" OR product_color ilike "%red%")
      AND product_type = 1
)
SELECT product_name,
       product_color,
       (ARRAY_AGG("product_distributor"))[1] AS "product_distributor",
       (ARRAY_AGG("product_release"))[1]     AS "product_release",
       COUNT(*) AS "count"
FROM       product p
INNER JOIN selected_products sp
        ON p.id = sp.id
GROUP BY product_name, 
         product_color
LIMIT 1000 
OFFSET 0
```

Then create an index on the "*product.id*" field as follows:

```
CREATE INDEX product_ids_idx ON product USING HASH (id);
```